# Sentry don't upload DSYMs files to S3 filestore backend and giving me exception: NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey)

Tags: amazon-s3, openshift, sentry, ceph

I am using on-premise Sentry in a OpenShift. 
I want to be able to use the S3 bucket to upload dsym files.
While trying to upload dsym files from the sentry-cli using the below command I am getting error:

```
sentry-cli upload-dif -t dsym --project service-level-reporting --log-level debug
```

sentry-worker log:

```
 [ERROR] celery.worker.job: Task sentry.tasks.assemble.assemble_dif[01205ec8-fb54-4cc0-ae48-ce75bb96f880] raised unexpected: NoSuchKey(u'An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: Unknown',) (data={u'hostname': 'celery@sentry-worker-42-mw42p', u'name': 'sentry.tasks.assemble.assemble_dif', u'args': '[]', u'internal': False, u'kwargs': "{'chunks': ['7f91f5edfe5ce6650448c3edf6cdea6bed5a3699'], 'checksum': '7f91f5edfe5ce6650448c3edf6cdea6bed5a3699', 'project_id': 7L, 'name': 'libswiftos.dylib'}", u'id': '01205ec8-fb54-4cc0-ae48-ce75bb96f880'})
```

I have checked my pods that the target S3 bucket is accessible. Could someone please help us to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't set you aws keys for sentry cli or you are requesting to S3 with wrong keys. If you didn't configure `sentry-cli` for aws keys maybe this can help you: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-docs/pull/956/files?short_path=b1d11e7#diff-b1d11e7d8a13bff13c9b3012f58e0b71